# Sorting a 2D Char Array in Alpha order?

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort a 2D array of names into alphabetical order, but I can not seam to get it to work.

I am using a bubble sort on the letters, and this is sorting the 1st letter of the names fine, but 3 of the names start with the same letter and they are still out of order.

I have tried googleing and stuff but every ting says to use vectors or string variables.. but I am limited to using 2d char arrays..

Any ideas?

Here is the code I have at the moment that works nearly:

```
using namespace std;

int main (){

    char heroes[11][17] = { "Captain America", "Thor", "Wolverine", "Cyclops", "Goliath", "Beast", "Angel", "Colossus", "Hulk", "Quicksilver", "Ironman"};

    cout<<"Printing the array as is"<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
        cout<<heroes[i]<<endl;
    }

    cout<<endl<<"Ordering the heroes in Alphabetical order"<<endl<<endl;

    char temp = NULL;
    // bubble sort
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<(11-1); j++){
            if (heroes[i][0] < heroes[j][0]){
                for (int k=0; k<17-1; k++){
                    swap(heroes[i][k], heroes[j][k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"Printing the array Sorted"<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
        cout<<heroes[i]<<endl;
    }

    // Pause
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<"Please Close Console Window"<<endl;
    cin.ignore('\n', 1024);
    return(0);
}
```

Ok I got it worked out!!!

http://ideone.com/ugLZ7

Here is the code... (how do i post code on this form btw?)

It is nearly exactly teh same but using complete string comparisons and copies.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `strcmp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have understood bubble-sort correctly. Firstly, you are supposed to be comparing adjacent elements only, and secondly, you need to check beyond the first character if matches for two elements. I made the necessary modifications, and the relevant part of the properly working code is:

```
int n=11,k,l;
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n-i-1; j++){
        l = min(strlen(heroes[j]),strlen(heroes[j+1]));
        for(k=0;k<l;++k)
            if(heroes[j+1][k]<heroes[j][k]){ swap(heroes[j],heroes[j+1]); break; }
            else if(heroes[j+1][k]>heroes[j][k]) break;
        if(k==l and strlen(heroes[j])>strlen(heroes[j+1]))
            swap(heroes[j],heroes[j+1]);
        }
    }
```

PS : You don't need to output the array using for loops that have 12 iterations. The last iteration just produces garbage values.

Comment: interesting.,. but dose not compile :(

Comment: you need to include the cstring library for it to work. also, i'm assuming you have a properly defined swap function that works for strings the way i've used it.

Answer (score 1):

Try and rely on the standard library to do the heavy lifting for you, what you are writing is really C with `std::cout` and isn't encouraged.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> > heroes { 
        "Captain America", "Thor", "Wolverine", "Cyclops", 
        "Goliath", "Beast", "Angel", "Colossus", "Hulk", 
        "Quicksilver", "Ironman"
    };

    std::sort(heroes.begin(), heroes.end());

    std::copy(heroes.begin(), heroes.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you don't have C++11 then you will need to add the elements to the vector manually using:

```
std::vector<std::string> > heroes;
heroes.push_back("Captain America");
...
```

Comment: as i said I am nto allowed to use anything but a cray

Comment: @aJynks This must be the stupidest restriction ever. My sympathy.

Comment: @aJynks where did you say that? & what is cray? also if you can't use the standard library then you aren't writing C++.

Comment: Also if you can't use the std lib why are you using `cout` and using namesace `std`

Comment: @ajynks but why? If you don't want to do it this way then you might be better off asking with the 'c' tag rather than C++ because this in't the c++ way.

Answer (score 1):

Using strcmp Function & Bubble Sort Method:

```
char temp[20];
int size = 11;
for(int i=1; i<size; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<size-i;j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(heroes[j],heroes[j+1]) > 0)
        {
            strcpy(temp, heroes[j]);
            strcpy(heroes[j], heroes[j+1]);
            strcpy(heroes[j+1], temp);
        }
    }
}
```