# how to sort array of c++ strings alphabetically

Tags: c++, sorting

I have an array of structs, and inside this struct I have a string variable that holds player names. I want to sort these names by their FIRST character only. 
I've tried to use the `>` and `<` operators but I cant get it to work correctly. I also don't have access to any `C++11` stuff.

```
void sort(player * player_array, num_players){
    string sorted[num_players];
    for(int i = 0; i < num_players; i++){
        if(player_array[i].name > player_array[i+1].name){
            sorted += player_array[i+1].name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't just downvote because you can, try to actually help.

Comment: put some code whatever you tried.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a 2D Char Array in Alpha order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750011/sorting-a-2d-char-array-in-alpha-order)

Comment: Please visit the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: How do you expect your code to work? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: ok added code that ive tried, any help at all plz?

Comment: You need to go through your code and think about what each line is supposed to do. [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is really helpful here.

Comment: Hint:  `std::sort`.  You can write a custom comparator if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your algorithm is wrong. Try making a few examples and run them by hand.
Try this code instead:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool comp(string a, string b)
{
    return a[0] < b[0];
}

void sort(player *player_array, num_players)
{
    string sorted[num_players];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; ++i)
        sorted[i] = player_array[i].name;
    std::sort(sorted, sorted + num_players, comp);
}
```

This solution uses std::sort so complexity is O(n log n). But since you are only sorting the names by their first character, it can be optimized down to O(n) using counting sort.